# iPad issue : Selecting a video from the videos folder using UIImagePicker

Tags: ipad

I created an app that allows the user to select a video from the photo Library 
e.g

self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

However, on the iPad you have a videos directory which if you drag a video in to iTunes, the video gets put in this directory.

How can I access this directory from a UIImagePicker or cant I?  Do I need to use a different type of picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the mobilecoreservices framework to you project. import the <mobilecoreservices/uicoretypes> and run the [imagepicker setmediatypes[nsarray arraywithobjects:(nsstring *)kuttypemovie, nil]]; method.